# ERROR : Parameter 64 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Even though all fields of my schema are varchar

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark

[sql server table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezeqt.png)

While I'm loading data from excel to MS sql-server using spark,and even though my all fields are of varchar type in sql server table, I'm getting this disruption. I don't know how to overcome this using java code.

```
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2814)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2678)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2133)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[task-result-getter-3] WARN  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Lost task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 19, 192.168.0.103, executor driver): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 64 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2814)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2678)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7375)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1(JdbcUtils.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$saveTable$1$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:994)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2133)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: parameter 64 - that's scary

Comment: Check the schema of the target table again, the error message seems pretty self-explanatory: `Parameter 64 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values.` Either you're selecting the wrong value to send in a `float` column or you need to send a `null` instead.

Comment: I have just added table schema in the image, can you please check that and tell me what I'm doing wrong. because there is no float(I have only varchar(max))  type field in the schema.

Comment: You do not show the 64th field

Comment: Added 64th field also

Comment: There appears to be a bug in your code - and no one can help you solve it without seeing your code. In addition, posting images is highly discouraged for many reasons. Worse, your image is simply a list of numbers and partial datatypes (at best) without any context. Your question is likely to be closed if you cannot supply useful information about your issue in an appropriate manner.

Comment: Look at the recommendation for writing a good question, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask... Add example code, avoid pictures when they do not bring any additional value, etc.

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to that.